# Why won't Family Sharing work?

Tags: family-sharing

I'm not understanding the iOS App Store's algorithm for Family Sharing of applications.

Here's how it works (for me):

> If user A shares with use B and wants a free app that A owns, it
>   is impossible to download (the App Store asking for A's credit card security
>   code and then rejects it); but if B wants a *paid* app that A owns,
>   don’t even use Family Sharing and just charge them.

I'm puzzled by this, since it seems not to be the advertised function of Family Sharing. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you are signed into the App Store with User B's Apple ID associated with Family Sharing? It sounds like User B maybe didn't accept the invite somehow and instead just signed into the device with User A's account. (Also, not all content is eligible for Family Sharing per Apple, though it doesn't specify _what_ is not eligible.)

Comment: @tubedogg: B is signed in, and Family Sharing has been enabled for some time (and has not behaved this way before, that either A or B can recall).

Comment: FWIW: A is getting notifications of $1 charges from the iOS App Store on my credit card, which confirms that the security code A is entering is correct and is being confirmed by the bank. The iOS App Store, however, still rejects it.

Comment: CVV (security code) is not a requirement to authorize funds. It is generally checked after funds are confirmed available. I'd double-check with your bank, and then call Apple.

Comment: @tubedogg: The iOS App Store on B's device won't let the download of the free and shared app proceed without the CVV, and the correct one is rejected by the store (though apparently accepted by the bank).

Comment: Given that this just started occurring, and it is asking for a CVV, it appears there is some problem in charging the card, whether it's on Apple's end or your bank's. Like I said, I'd call your bank and then Apple. Nobody here is going to be able to resolve issues with your payment method.

Comment: @tubedogg: Any idea why this only happen for free apps we share? For paid apps it doesn't even bother, and just charges to B's account (effectively circumventing sharing and double charging for the app).

Comment: You can't download (or update for that matter) any apps, free or not, if Apple thinks there is a problem with the payment method. I don't know why it is using User B's account, though.

Comment: @tubedogg: It switches to B's account if it can charge B. If there's nothing to charge, it stays with sharing (and blocks, as you say). I've verified with the bank that there is no problem with the card (and that the test charges I was seeing would confirm that for me).